# Capture screen with CGWindowListCreateImage just return the wallpaper

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I'm trying to create an app that can take screenshots. I check to see if I have a secure session and if I has graphical access and I do. But all I get is my app windows and the wallpaper. No other apps are captured.

I tried to use the `screencapture`. It work well in terminal but not in the app. Also each time I try the function it asks me to give permission even thought it already has permission.

This is my code:

```
var attrs = SessionAttributeBits(rawValue: 0)
let session = SessionGetInfo(callerSecuritySession, nil, &attrs)

if session != 0 || !attrs.contains(.sessionHasGraphicAccess) {
  result(FlutterError(code: "NO_GRAPHIC_ACCESS", message: "We don't run in a GUI.", details: nil))
} else {
  do {
    let directory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let image = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect.infinite, [.optionOnScreenOnly, .excludeDesktopElements], kCGNullWindowID, .nominalResolution)
    if let _image = image {
      let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: _image)
      let data = bitmap.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])

      if let _data = data {
        let url: URL = directory.appendingPathComponent("\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000000)).png")
        try _data.write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)
      } else {
        result(FlutterError(code: "IMAGE_REPRESENTATION_FAILED", message: nil, details: nil))
      }
    } else {
      result(FlutterError(code: "IMAGE_IS_NULL", message: nil, details: nil))
    }
  } catch {
    result(FlutterError(code: "ERROR", message: "\(error)", details: nil))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a strange XCode behavior. If you run your application directly from XCode, user will always be prompted to confirm permission, even if your app is already in you settings exceptions (https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/mac).

If you archive your application and install it in your mac, then permissions will be asked only once. It seems that every build of the app in XCode generate a new app, this don't happen in iOS and iPadOS simulators or devices.

Answer (score 0):

Give your program permissions for screen recording. See [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/mac).